# Writing a value from a row into the another row and column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to "marry" two imaginary people in my DB. What I want to do is select people within a certain age-range and then write each others IDs in a column.

If this is my table

```
ID | sex | age | married to
 1 | M   | 25  | NULL
 2 | F   | 28  | NULL
 3 | M   | 75  | NULL
```

The result should look something like this:

```
ID | sex  | age | married_to
 1 | M    | 25  | 2
 2 | F    | 28  | 1
 3 | M    | 75  | NULL
```

I know the select-statement should look something like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE age BETWEEN ageMin AND ageMax AND married_to IS NULL
```

But I don't know how to get SQLite to write the ID in the right column. Espacially how to make this work in a DB with about 150k entries. For me the tricky part is to always just write into one row without having a super slow program. Could somebody help me out?

Comment: What should happen when there is a Male `M` with age `26` in between ID `1` and `2`

Comment: The partner should be selected randomly. Age is the only independent variable. It doesn't matter if some people end up not getting "married".

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to capture two IDs. One for person A and one for person B, to be married.

Next, you will need to perform two update queries once you have the IDs:

1. Update person A's "married to" to equal person B's ID
2. Update person B's "married to" to equal person A's ID

SQLite allows you to [select a random row](http://www.bernzilla.com/2008/05/13/selecting-a-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table/).

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE age BETWEEN ageMin 
      AND ageMax AND married_to IS NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

You could do this twice, check to ensure the IDs are separate, and then perform the update queries.

```
UPDATE table SET married_to = Person_B_ID WHERE ID = *Person A's ID*
```

and

```
UPDATE table SET married_to = Person_A_ID  WHERE ID = *Person B's ID*
```

You can run this sequence of queries any number of times. However, the performance of RANDOM() may not be suitable for a large database. If this is the case you may want to run a query to get all the IDs of people who need to be married, and then match those up using some other programming language. You could then automatically generate the update queries to "marry" the pairs in the database.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The second part is my problem. I would like it to be faster. I am using Java, would you know how to begin implementing a solution in that language?